# HTTP streaming mp4 video on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, video-streaming, mp4

I have some mp4 files stored on one of my servers. The files have been encoded to H.264. I created a page  on another server and embedded a html5 video.

```
<video width='400' height='300'><source src='videourl' type='video/mp4' /></video>
```

When the video is playing on ipad over 3G, it's really slow. Sometimes it stopped playing and I had to click the video again to continue.

I wonder how to make it play the video smoothly over 3G? Is there any server requirements/configuration for streaming the mp4 videos on ipad?

Answer (score 1):

what is the bitrate of the video ? the quality of playback is highly dependent on bandwidth. Can you verify that the video is playing smoothly over wifi.

Comment: The bit rate  is about 1330kbps. Is that too high?  The video does play smoothly over wifi.